# Using XDocument in XNA on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

I have some perfectly working code using XDocument, XMLWriter etc but when I try to add it to my XNA 4.0 game it doesn't work.

I get the following compilation errors, even though I have all the required references referenced and usings used as shown here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
```

> The type or namespace name 'XmlTextWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'XmlNodeList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure your `XNA Game Project` has a reference to `System.Xml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you developing a **Windows Store App**, you may want to check the following thread...

[How to rectify Namespace errors in a Windows Store class library in Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227099/how-to-rectify-namespace-errors-in-a-windows-store-class-library-in-windows-8-an)