# How to rectify Namespace errors in a Windows Store class library in Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm developing a classlibrary(Windows Store Apps) for XMPP in windows 8, I'm Getting these errors, I'd given all the required references like,

```
System.Net
System.Threading
```

and so on, But Still these errors arises,

> Error  15  The type or namespace name 'Formatting' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  16  The type or namespace name 'Formatting' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  17  The type or namespace name 'Formatting' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  7   The type or namespace name 'ICloneable' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  9   The type or namespace name 'IPAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  12  The type or namespace name 'IPAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  13  The type or namespace name 'IPEndPoint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  6   The type or namespace name 'ListDictionary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  14  The type or namespace name 'ListDictionary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  2   The type or namespace name 'Sockets' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  3   The type or namespace name 'Sockets' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  4   The type or namespace name 'Sockets' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  5   The type or namespace name 'Stack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  1   The type or namespace name 'Timer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  8   The type or namespace name 'Timer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  10  The type or namespace name 'Timer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  18  The type or namespace name 'XmlTextWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   
>   Error  11  Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue' requires 1 type arguments

Please anyone help me or suggest me the solution. . .

```
/// <summary>
/// returns the Xml, difference to the Xml property is that you can set formatting properties
/// </summary>
/// <param name="format"></param>
/// <param name="indent"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string ToString(Formatting format, int indent)
{           
    return BuildXml(this, format, indent, ' ');
}

#region << Xml Serializer Functions >>

private string BuildXml(Node e, Formatting format, int indent, char indentchar)
{
    if ( e != null )
    {
        System.IO.StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter w = new XmlTextWriter(tw);
        w.Formatting    = format;
        w.Indentation   = indent;
        w.IndentChar    = indentchar;

        WriteTree(this, w, null);

        return tw.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The 'Formatting' error is coming from this code block, Even though i've given the reference as system.xml

Theres no Option to Resolve,

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2012 showing errors]

Comment: "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: "I'm not a Beginner, I know a lot" --- seems like reading error message is an extra skill nowadays

Comment: I've added the references sir, System.Net for Socket, System.Xml for Formatting, System.Thread for Timer, But it gives me these errors. . .

Comment: @ggsmartboy: if it still gives it - then you haven't

Comment: Are you running under Client Profile?

Comment: @zerkms In Windows8 and VS 2012 All the Framework assemblies are already referenced. I've Already referenced Sir. . .

Comment: check your project target framework and referenced assembly framework. Your project target framework is lesser than referenced.

Comment: @Yograj Gupta This is Windows Store Class Library Sir.

Comment: Please update your title to be less vague. Otherwise, it will not be useful to future visitors of the site (and therefore may be close for being too localized). Note that the error message has two suggestions, but you fixed only one. Even the red underlines in the IDE should be a clue.

Comment: @Raymond Chen What is the Other one Sir. .

Comment: "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" You repeat many times that you added the assembly reference but you never mentioned adding the necessary `using` directives.

Comment: I've done that too Sir,  Using System.Net;,Using System.Threading;,Using System.Xml;

Comment: Well, the directive isn't working. Notice that all your identifiers in the System.Xml namespace have red squiggles. Maybe you put your `using` directives in the wrong place.

Comment: No Sir! Not like that appears in my project

Comment: This is a language/culture barrier thing, but I'm going to go ahead and say it: I know you are only being polite, but it is a bit awkward that you call everyone "Sir", *every time*. Some people may find it abrasive... Just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [quick google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=returns%20the%20Xml,%20difference%20to%20the%20Xml%20property%20is%20that%20you%20can%20set%20formatting%20properties&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&source=hp&channel=np#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=VH0&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&channel=np&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22returns%20the%20Xml,%20difference%20to%20the%20Xml%20property%20is%20that%20you%20can%20set%20formatting%20properties%22&oq=%22returns%20the%20Xml,%20difference%20to%20the%20Xml%20property%20is%20that%20you%20can%20set%20formatting%20properties%22&gs_l=serp.3...2689.3041.0.3263.2.2.0.0.0.0.72.141.2.2.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.kKuu-ogyThc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=a3172285415346e8&bpcl=37189454&biw=1680&bih=921) for one of the comments in the code you've provided, I found that it's from [here](http://svn.apocdev.com/quickirc/trunk/QuickIRC2/Jabber/agsXMPP/Xml/Dom/Node.cs).

As this isn't your own code (I assume - perhaps incorrectly!) that you're attempting to compile for Windows Store Apps which presently targets the [3.5 framework](http://svn.apocdev.com/quickirc/trunk/QuickIRC2/QuickIRC2.csproj) and has references to things such as `System.Windows.Forms` listed in the project file, it'll likely not work until you rewrite portions of the code to target the Windows Store version of the framework. For example, `XmlTextWriter` is not listed under the `System.Xml` namespace in the [.NET For Windows Store Apps] API[4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454055.aspx/system.xml%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

In short - code for the "full" .net Framework cannot (other than the simplest of snippets) just be recompiled targeting the Windows Store .NET API.

Comment: I noticed that earlier Sir, now I'm altering those codes, I'm searching for the replacement of those things such as, XmlTextWriter,Sockets,CollectionBase and so on. .  Can You help!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't - I'm not at all familiar with the Windows Store Apps API. What I do know is that you probably **won't** be able to just do a "search and replace", because of the very different way it's all structured (async, etc,...). You'll most likely need to do a ground-up rewrite of large chunks of the code.

Comment: Well Thanks a lot. . . I'm working on it. . . Meanwhile if u find anything that helps me please say me. . .